# Sphinx Get Word in Result through PHP API

Tags: php, sphinx

The Sphinx PHP API returns a "matches" array after executing "Query();".  It also returns a "Words" array.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way that for each match in the "matches" array if it would show what word was used to give that result it's weight.

For example, my query is...
`"Green Banana | Yellow Banana"`

The results look something like.

```
[18403206462384766539] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 4553
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )
```

What I'd love to see is something more like.

```
[18403206462384766539] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 4553
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                    )
                [word] => "Green Banana"
            )
```

I want to avoid having to make two separate queries and then having to compare the weights across both result arrays to find the highest one because I plan on having a query with many hundreds or thousands of OR'd phrases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. There is however `PACKEDFACTORS()` - which might give you some useful information.

Its a function so can be used in the `SetSelect call.